# Any way to force PyCharm to refresh its understanding of a virtual environment, other than quit & restart?

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 3.4.1, and I've configured it to use an interpreter from a Python 3.4 venv.

However, when I do an external "pip install" of additional packages to the venv, PyCharm's code analysis still highlights references as being unsatisfied. (Most recently, after installing a package as editable source.)

Quitting & restarting resolves the issue. But is there any other way to kick/refresh PyCharm's idea of what's available to the venv interpreter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Help > Find Action`:

→ *`Rescan Available Python Modules and Packages`*

Available from PyCharm 2020.1.2 ([YouTrack Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21659))

Comment: Not available in 2022.3.2 Community Edition

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this by editing the interpreter path of the environment you are using, then editing it back and applying. Still not perfect, but you don't have to restart PyCharm.

You can edit it in Preferences/Project/Project Interpreter. Click on cog wheel next to the dropdown interpreters.

Comment: Nice idea - unfortunately it didn't work for me, using the latest version of PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the terminal in Pycharm. It worked for me.If not you can try below

[Interpreter Settings..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySgob.png)

Look for the packages updated, if not press "+" and add.

[Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mRsW.png)

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is pressing File->Reload all from disk
(or simply Ctrl+Alt+Y)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues but with replacing `venv` in PyCharm. First, I initialized `venv` with one version of Python. I opened PyCharm and it has been cached somewhere. I removed `venv` and created another one with different Python version. Unfortunately I PyCharm was still using the old, not existing `venv`.

I needed to add existing interpreter, coming from `venv`:

1. Pycharm / Settings
2. Project <> / Python Interpreter
3. Open the list, Show all
4. Choose the one connected to the project (the cached one) and remove it. Click ok
5. Add Interpreter / Add Local Interpreter
6. Environment: Existing
7. Path: `<path to your project>/venv/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

For Anaconda env, please make sure, you're *pip install some_package* with pip.exe from the correct environment, i.e.:

```
c:\Users\some_user\.conda\envs\py38\Scripts\pip.exe install some_package
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another possible answer:

In the Project tree select external libraries -> the library you want to rescan, right click -> reload from disk.

Adding this here because it might be faster than rescanning all libraries or all files.